# Group table by custom column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `transaction_transaction` with columns:

```
id, status, total_amount, date_made, transaction_type
```

The status can be: `Active, Paid, Trashed, Renewed, Void`

So what i want to do is filter by date and status, but since sometimes there are no records with Renewed or Trashed, i get inconsistent data it returns only `Active and Paid` when grouping by status ( notice `Renewed and Trashed` is missing ). I want it allways to return smth like:

```
-----------------------------------
Active   | 121          | 2017-08-09
Paid     | 122          | 2017-08-19
Trashed  | 123          | 2017-08-20
Renewed  | 123          | 2017-08-20
```

The sql query i use:

```
SELECT
    ST.type,
    COALESCE(SUM(TR.total_amount), 0) AS amount
FROM sms_admin_status ST
LEFT JOIN transaction_transaction TR ON TR.status = ST.type
WHERE TR.store_id = 21 AND TR.transaction_type = 'Layaway' AND TR.status != 'Void'
    AND TR.date_made >= '2018-02-01' AND TR.date_made <= '2018-02-26'
GROUP BY ST.type
```

*Edit: I created a table sms_admin_status since you said its bad not having a table and in the future i might have new statuses, and i also changed the query to fit my needs.*

Comment: You will need to have a list of all possible statuses somewhere. It could be a table, hard coded in the query, or anything else so that even if there is no data, the query knows to show that status with 0 count. Also, your sample data has `Deleted` row but your description you say that its missing? You are not using `GROUP BY` so not sure what results you expect to see.

Comment: Can you please show me a way how to hard-code a column and group by that column ?
I fixed the query, cause this is an example i took, to describe my problem shortly.

Comment: Radim has posted a solution with hard coding. As he mentioned as well, this is not a good solution and should be avoided. This can cause lot of issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (not very nice one) is the following

```
select statuses.s, date_made, coalesce(SUM(amount), 0)
from (values('active'),('inactive'),('deleted')) statuses(s)
left join transactions t on statuses.s = t.status and
   date_made >= '2017-08-08'
group by statuses.s, date_made
```

I assume that you forgot to add `date_made` to the `group by`. therefore, I added it there. As you can see the possible values are hardcoded in the SQL. Some other solution (much more cleaner) is to create a table with possible values of status and replace my `statuses`.

Comment: This still is not showing all the statuses. 
It shows only the statuses that have records during this period.

Comment: Radim i updated the question, i also created a `sms_admin_status` table, and im grouping by that but still its not giving me all the statuses

Answer (score 1):

Use a VALUES list in a subquery to LEFT JOIN your transaction table. You may need to NULLIF your sums to have them return 0.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-values.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT ... FROM (VALUES)` with restriction from the transaction table:

```
select * from (values('active', 0),('inactive', 0),('deleted', 0)) as statuses
  where column1 not in (select status from transactions)
union select status, sum(amount) from transactions group by status
```

Add the date column as need be, I assume it's a static value

Comment: I updated the question, for the status now im using a table.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple where statements will limit the rows selected unless they are in a sub-query. May I suggest something like the following?

```
    SELECT ST.type, ISNULL(SELECT SUM(TR.total_amount)
                       FROM transaction_transaction TR
                     WHERE TR.status = ST.type AND TR.store_id = 21 AND TR.transaction_type = 'Layaway' AND TR.status != 'Void'
                       AND TR.date_made >= '2018-02-01' AND TR.date_made <= '2018-02-26'),0) AS amount
    FROM sms_admin_status ST
    GROUP BY ST.type
```

Comment: I found a way to fix the issue, this works with `COALESCE` instead of IS NULL but this solution is no that elegant and useful